# Getting 400 error ( invalid argument - latlng )while updating the location details via Google my business API

Tags: google-maps, google-my-business-api

I've a business published in Google My business.It is in live. I tried to update the location details via API. But I'm getting 400 error and getting the following response.

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": 400,
    "message": "Request contains an invalid argument.",
    "status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT",
    "details": [
      {
        "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.mybusiness.v4.ValidationError",
        "errorDetails": [
          {
            "code": 3,
            "field": "latlng",
            "message": "The specified address cannot be located. Please use the UI to provide a pin drop."
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

But in the above scenario, patch request doesn't contains the location coordinates. But I still getting the specified address cannot be located  response.

Body of patch request::

```
{
  "primaryPhone": "xxxxxxxxx",
  "locationName": "xxxx",
  "address": {
    "regionCode": "IN",
    "postalCode": "xxxxx",
    "locality": "xxxxx",
    "addressLines": [
      "xxxxxx xxxx xxxx"
    ],
    "administrativeArea": "xxxx xxxxxx"
  },
  "primaryCategory": {
    "displayName": "Apartment building",
    "categoryId": "gcid:apartment_building"
  },
  "languageCode": "en",
  "storeCode": "xxxxxx9dda0dc5-c709-410c-a272-912486b1b5f4"
}
```

This is doesn't contains the lat,lng but still getting the same lat,lng field error.

Actually I've changed the name  only change . I don't know how it is related to lat,lng.

And tried  updating without the address field and with address field. But in both case getting the same response.

Comment: And why don't you provide the `latlng` parameter?

Comment: Also I voted to close your question because you should provide a [mcve] that allows to reproduce the problem. It is unclear how you send the request, to which endpoint, etc.

Comment: Google my business api allows "latlng" only the creation of the location.

Comment: That would be clear if we knew which API method you are using and how. So that doesn't change anything to what I asked for earlier: [mcve]

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you are using this method (https://developers.google.com/my-business/reference/rest/v4/accounts.locations/patch).

This error occurs when Google determines that their own Geocoder doesn't really know where they should be placing the pin for that address. So additionally to the address property, Google may(!) allow you to also send them the latLng property - if Google determines that this is a credible set of coordinates, the address will be updated.
It is however still possible that they won't believe you that you know where that address is exactly. In that case, the only way to get address data through is in fact to go to the Google My Business UI of the location and manually dragging that pin to where it needs to go.